# How create Subplots from and use a common legend on matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have two three vectors: V1, V2, and V3;
where size(V1)= size(V2) = size(V3) =6;
I want to pot in the spot(3,2,1)==> [V1(1),V2(1),V3(1)] and spot(3,2,1)==>[V1(2),V2(2),V3(2)] ...etc.
Then I want to appear one legend. as the follow picture:

[image]

I tried programming the following code:

```
x1=[1;2;3]
y1 = [91,25,3];
y2 = [71,22,13];
y3 = [81,22,33];
y4 = [71,12,63];
y5 = [61,42,23];
y6 = [51,21,23];
    
figure;

subplot(3,2,1);
b1=bar(x1,y1);
ylabel('Cost per Byte (%)');
ylim([0 max(y1)+10]);
title('(a)');
    
subplot(3,2,2);
b2=bar(x1,y2);
ylabel('Security (%)');
ylim([0 max(y2)+10]);

title('(b)');

subplot(3,2,3);
b3=bar(x1,y3);
ylabel('Data rate (kbps)');
ylim([0 max(y3)+10]);
title('(c)');

subplot(3,2,4);
b4=bar(x1,y4);
ylabel('Delay (ms)');
ylim([0 max(y4)+10]);

title('(d)');

subplot(3,2,5);
b5=bar(x1,y5);
ylabel('Jitter (ms)');
ylim([0 max(y5)+10]);
title('(e)');
subplot(3,2,6);
b6=bar(x1,y6);
ylabel('Loss ratio 10^6 (ms)');
ylim([0 max(y6)+10]);
title('(f)');
legend([b1,b1],'Bar Chart 1','Bar Chart 2')
set(b1(1),'FaceColor','red');
    
%set(gcf,'Units','Inches');
%pos = get(gcf,'Position');
%set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','Auto','PaperUnits','Inches','PaperSize',[pos(3), pos(4)])
%print(gcf,'Brm','-dpdf','-r0')
```

But I have not a positive results.

Comment: you make a legend in the last plot, and then you change its position

Comment: This might be a tangential question, but why do you need any legend here? Just label your x-axes... If your "real" example is more complex then please reflect that in your example, since this would likely require a custom function for any sort of generic example (likely based on Ander's comment), but that might not be applicable if you've over-simplified